# Multidimensional distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

It is known that if $F:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ is an Stieltjes measure function such that $\inf F(x)=0$ and $\sup F(x)=1$, then there is a random variable $X$ whose distribution function is $F$.

> Is there an analogous result for multidimensional Stieltjes measure functions $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to[0,1]$ such that $\inf F(\mathbf{x})=0$ and $\sup F(\mathbf{x})=1$? Could you please give me a reference of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Theorem 1.1.11 in Durrett, Probability Theory and Examples, 5th Edition, is what you are looking for:
https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf